# divs floating and other users view

Tags: html, layout, css-float

I have a webpage i created and i use css and div floats to position everything.  On my monitor as I develop it all looks great.  I show a co-worker, and all the divs overlap and look terrible.  below is an example.

---css----

```
 #div1{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid;
    .....
    }
 #div2{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    .....
    }
```

----page----

```
  <div id='div1'>Hello</div>
  <div id='div2'>How are you?</div>
  <div id='div2'>What is your favorite color?</div>
```

in this example I made up.  it would look great for me.  on other user screen,  "Hello" will overlap the div1 border. and "how are you" would overlap the color question by a letter or two...

i know this may be vague, but Im not sure how else to ask....

Comment: Is the duplicate ID a typo?

Comment: Yes it's very vague. If you can provide 2 screenshots/pics of the two results, or at the very least provide the full CSS for the 2 divs, post me an @Tyblitz comment here and I'll be able to help you. Atm, there are too many possible bug causers.

Comment: would help if you mention what browser the error is happening on that might speed things up

Comment: I figured it out,  I was using divs with a percentage, and text was form fields, that were X pixels wide....so they were overlapping the div borders...sorry for the crappy question..